# How to use custom file for ajax instead admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

WordPress site made basket. There, by clicking on the button, an ajax request is sent to the server, processing goes through PHP. Basket storage - a cookie. Timing shows that the main brake occurs precisely when transferring data from js to PHP and vice versa. Js and PHP itself work fine. It sends the form to PHP. Back - JSON string.

I read this topics:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315374/how-to-speed-up-admin-ajax-php-in-wordpress,
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could,
- https://wp-kama.ru/id_3014/podgruzhaem-sredu-wordpress-s-minimalnoy-nagruzkoy-konstanta-shortinit.html.

But I have ready the site and me afraid to use SHORTIN , because I don't know what could happen with other wp functions.
I tried to use themes/my-theme/custom.php instead of admin-ajax.php, but it doesn't have context. My cookie does not work correctly without COOKIEPATH.

I think, maybe mya afraid SHORTINT for nothing? Or what I do incorrectly in the second variant?

My code:
`function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 ); 
function myajax_data(){ 
    wp_localize_script('main', 'myajax', 
        array( 
      'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
      'testurl' => get_home_url(null, 'wp-content/themes/my-theme/test.php')
        ) 
    ); 
}
```

`main.js`

```
  $('.bars-addproduct').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $form = $(this).serializeArray();
      $.ajax({
        url: myajax.testurl, 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          action: "addProduct",
          form: $form,
        },
        success: function (res) { 
         console.log(res);
        }
   });
});
```

`test.php`

```
<?php
$name_cookie_basket = 'users_basket';
$cookies_time = time() + 60*24; //24min

    $res = '';
    $form = $_POST['form'];
    foreach ($form as $field) {
      switch ($field['name']) {
        case 'productID':
          $productID = $field['value'];
          break;
        case 'name':
          $name = $field['value'];
          break;
        case 'price':
          $price = $field['value'];
          break;
        case 'count':
          $count = $field['value'];
          break;
        case 'amount':
          $amount = $field['value'];
          break;
        case 'ownerID':
          $ownerID = $field['value'];
          break;
      }
    }
    $cookie_basket = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE[$name_cookie_basket]), true);
    $products = $cookie_basket['products'];
    $isModify = false;
    $i = 0;

    if (!$isModify) {
      // если это не редактирование, а добавление
      //Сначала проверим данные
      if (((is_numeric($productID)) || ($productID == '')) &&
          ((is_numeric($price)) || ($price == '')) &&
          ((is_numeric($count)) || ($count == '')) &&
          ((is_numeric($amount)) || ($amount == '')) &&
          ((is_numeric($ownerID))) &&
          ((($amount != '') && (intval($amount) >= 0) && ($count == '')) ||   //это пополнение депозита
            (($productID != '') && (intval($count) >= 0) && ($amount == ''))
           )   
      ){
        //если все ок, добавляем
        $newProduct = [
          'productID' => $productID,
          'name' => $name,
          'price' => $price,
          'count' => intval($count),
          'amount' => intval($amount),
          'ownerID' => $ownerID,
        ];
        // add_row('bars_products', $newProduct, 'user_' . strval($current_user->ID));
        array_push($products, $newProduct);
        $res .= 'success added'."\n";
      } else {
        //если не ок
        $res = 'fail';
      }
    }
    $cookie_basket['products'] = $products;

    $success = setcookie($name_cookie_basket, json_encode($cookie_basket), $cookies_time, '/');
    if ($success) {
      $res = json_encode([$products]);
    } else {
      $res = 'fail';
    }

    echo $res;
    wp_die();
// }
```

Comment: _“I think, maybe mya afraid SHORTINT for nothing?”_ - I have no idea what you are even trying to ask here, sorry. What does any SHORTINT (primarily used as a name for a database data type) have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
In js file change the ajax code



$('.bars-addproduct').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).serializeArray();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'websitelink/ajax.php?callToAjax=true', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          action: "addProduct",
          form:  form,
        },
        success: function (res) { 
         console.log(res);
        }
   });
});

In ajax file add below code 
  // ajax call for save imap setting page
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'addProduct'){
   print_r($_POST);
     die;
}
```